# Is the duality product of dual spaces unique?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Consider, for example, the Sobolev space $H^1_0(\Omega)$. It is known that the dual is $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ and is Banach with respect to the operator norm

$$||f||_{-1} = \sup \limits_{v \in H^1_0} \dfrac{(f,v)}{||v||_1}. $$

Where $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the duality product, which is the $L^2$ inner product.

Can we define another duality product that can still be used to define the operator norm?

My question originates from trying to understand what is a duality product, to begin with, and why are we using the $L^2$ inner product for that. I encountered this in the study of PDEs.

In general, What if, for example, we use the $H^1$ inner product? Or what if we are looking for the duality product of a different space? How would one define the duality product?

Comment: Why do you say the duality product is the $L^2$ inner product? Elements of the dual space of a Banach space $X$ are continuous linear functionals on $X$. The duality product $(f,v)$ then just means evaluating the functional $f$ at the point $v$. 

In particular, $H^{-1}$ contains distributions that are not represented by $L^2$ functions so that $L^2$-inner product of $f \in H^{-1}$ and $v \in H_0^1$ need not be defined.

Comment: @RhysSteele Yes you are right! I think I am getting this all wrong. Do you know a reference to get started on this subject?

Comment: There are lots of textbooks on PDE that cover this kind of thing. I like Brezis' "functional analysis, sobolev spaces and partial differential equations" but there are also plenty of other options